# Processing, Running If Statement Twice Instead of One Time

Tags: java, if-statement, processing

I'm making really simple game, but I'm stuck with a weird problem; I want zombie to hit character when he can but, he hits me two times instead of one time.

```
void zombieAttack(float distance){
if(zombieCanAttack && (distance < charSizeX/2+zombieSize/2)){ 
  charApplyDamage(5);
  zombieAttackCounter_obj.counter(0); 
  zombieAttackCounter = 0;
  println("second " + zombieCanAttack);
  zombieCanAttack = false; 
}
```

}

I even deleted the code that makes zombieCanAttack true when the timer says so, so there is nothing that makes zombieCanAttack true, but even so program gives me this output two times: "second true". This causes zombie to hit character twice instead of one time. Why does it enters if statement twice?

Edit: Here is the full zombie class:

```
class Zombie {
  float zombieX, zombieY, zombieSizeX, zombieSizeY, zombieSize, zombieHp, zombieDamage,
  zombieSpeed, zombieThresholdX, zombieThresholdY, zombieAttackCounter;
  boolean zombieFlip, zombieCanAttack = true;
  Counter zombieAttackCounter_obj = new Counter();

  void instantiateZombie(float x, float y, float sizeX, float sizeY, float hp,
    float damage, float speed, int thresholdX, int thresholdY){
    zombieX = x;
    zombieY = y;
    zombieSizeX = sizeX;
    zombieSizeY = sizeY;
    zombieSize = (sizeX+sizeY)/4;
    zombieHp = hp;
    zombieDamage = damage;
    zombieSpeed = speed;
    zombieThresholdX = thresholdX;
    zombieThresholdY = thresholdY;
  }
  void zombieAI(){
    zombieAttackCounter = zombieAttackCounter_obj.counter(-1);
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(zombieX, zombieY, zombieSizeX, zombieSizeY);
    float distance = dist(charX, charY, zombieX, zombieY);
    if(distance+zombieSizeX/2 > charSizeX/2+zombieSizeX/2){
      zombieWalk();
    } else {
      zombieAttack(distance);
    }
    //println("first " + zombieCanAttack);
    if(zombieAttackCounter > 1.5){ /*zombieCanAttack = true; */}
  }
  void zombieWalk(){
    if(zombieX-charX < zombieThresholdX && zombieX-charX > -zombieThresholdX){ }
    else if(zombieX-charX < 0){ 
      zombieX+=zombieSpeed; zombieFlip = true; 
    } 
    else{ 
      zombieX-=zombieSpeed; zombieFlip = false; 
    }
    if(zombieY-charY < zombieThresholdY && zombieY-charY > -zombieThresholdY){ }
    else if(zombieY-charY < 0){ 
      zombieY+=zombieSpeed; 
    } 
    else{ 
      zombieY-=zombieSpeed; 
    }
  }
  void zombieAttack(float distance){
    if((zombieCanAttack) && (distance < charSizeX/2+zombieSize/2)){ 
      charApplyDamage(5);
      zombieAttackCounter_obj.counter(0); 
      zombieAttackCounter = 0;
      println("second " + zombieCanAttack);
      zombieCanAttack = false; 
    }  
  }
}
```

Here is the full .pde in any case: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7824949/

Comment: Paste your code and then explain it properly

Comment: Can you please show your whole class, so that we can run it and see what's going on?  It's impossible to find the needle when you've only given us half the haystack.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads running?

Comment: Other .pde's: Main http://paste.ubuntu.com/7825230/ 
Counter : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7825235/ 
Main Character: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7825237/

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  This should be a very simple debugging task.  If you don't have an interactive debugger then just insert println statements to track where you are and what values you have.

Comment: I know how to debug, the problem is I make zombieCanAttack false within the statement I use it, but it enters two times. And there is nothing makes zombieCanAttack true. Please don't waste my time and your time.

Comment: So you don't want anyone to waste their time looking at your code?

Comment: (How many Zombies are there??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HotLicks good point ... there is two zombies because of using this statement to add one zombie

```
for(int i = 0; i < zombieNumber+1; i++){
    zombieHolder.add(new Zombie());
}
```

where the value of `zombieNumber` is 1 and according to implementation of `Zombie` class they are with same parameters (why you instantiate them like this?) and move as one so they hit you twice ... try to increase the `zombieNumber` to see if this problem is really here.

Comment: My bad, I did instantiate them at the same coordinates so I couldn't see them, I didn't know there was 2 zombies. I was careless.